# jQuery .blur method not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

I am trying to set up an Ajax call whenever the user enters information into a particular field on my ASP MVC web page. Below is the jQuery `.blur` method

```
$('#MailingZip').blur(function () {
    alert("here");
    if ($('#MailingState').val() != "" && $('#div.channelName').text() != "") {
        alert("inside  Mailing Zip");
        getDrmTerritory($('#MailingZip').val(), $('#MailingState').val(), $('#div.channelName').text());
    }
});
```

and here is the control from the view.

```
    <div class="M-editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MailingZip)<span class="req">*</span>
    </div>
    <div class="M-editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MailingZip, new { maxlength = 15, onchange = "CheckTerritory('M');" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MailingZip)
    </div>
```

I just started w/jQuery a couple weeks ago, so I'm not sure what's wrong. FYI, none of the `alerts` are working and if I set a breakpoint at the first `if` statement it doesn't fire.

Comment: Did you put the above jQuery in to the `$(document).ready()` function?

Comment: I did not.. guessing that could be the problem?

Comment: add as an answer so I can accept. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you put your code inside of the `$(document).ready()` function, this ensures that the DOM is fully loaded before you manipulate any of its contents:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // your code here!
});
```